# Middle alignment of font icon with text on right

Tags: css

Following is my fiddle in which I am trying to vertically align the text with Icon Font. Kindly let me know what's an appropriate way to do such alignment:

How can I vertically align the font icon with the text on [this fiddle](http://bootply.com/gNv6sJCE3v)

```
Wrong output:
[ICON]Text
 Text Text 

Expected Output:

       Text
[ICON] Text
       Text
```

Comment: That's a bootply not a fiddle :) - so I suppose you need this using bootstrap

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/95XJeBzQlx something like this?

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML no not like that, icon is not vertically aligned and solution is not generic

Comment: @Danield nah using bootstrap css is not necessary, I just want to know how the trick works when icon is not an image and its a font

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the icon float (**[bootply #1](http://www.bootply.com/PunYraLmok)**):

```
.panel-title .glyphicon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

but I prefer using Block Formatting Context ([BFC](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/clearfix_block-formatting-context_and_hasLayout.asp)) properties when it comes after a floating element (needs an extra element to enclose your text). It basically creates a column along your float instead of letting your text wrap around it as usual (**[bootply #2](http://www.bootply.com/hMzqAO5MQn)**):

HTML:

```
<a href="#collapseFour">
    <span class="left mr1 glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
    <span class="bfc">Reports Reports Reports Reports Reports Reports Reports</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    float: left;
}
.bfc {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

div it.

put the icon in a separated div, like this:

```
<div>
    {icon}
</div>
<div>
    {text}
</div>
```

and put them inline. `display:inline-block`... this should work.

Comment: did you put the "display:inline-block" to both divs?

Comment: I have no idea what you did wrong, but here, i did a fiddle. I roughly did the situation, and you see it works. just make 2 blocks, displayed inline, it shall work. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B5jfx/

Answer (score -1):

you can make a little table like this

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle">[ICON]</td><td>Text<br>Text<br>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh boy, I know about this solution but don't really like this workaround. I thought there is some better way to do this

Comment: Please see [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) *whatyearisit.jpg*